# Angularjs push array of data retrieved from a resource service in another array in scope

Tags: angularjs

I´m trying to implement a pagination service. So, in a controller I have two methods to get a list of boats from my database (using a Rails API). To get the data the controller is using a service with a resource (simple query method):

```
.factory('Boat', 

      function($resource){          
        var boats =
         $resource('http://127.0.0.1\\:3000/:action', {}, {     
            query: {method:'GET', params:{action:'boats'}, isArray:true},
            getBoatsByBusinessId: {method:'GET', params:{action:'boatsByBusinessId'}, isArray:true}
         });        
         return boats;            
      }
  )
```

In my controller, I have two methods (maybe I could use just one, but I think this is not important this point):

```
$scope.getOptionList = function(departure, departureDate, arrivalDate, people) { 
  $scope.pagIndex = 0;                      
  $scope.boats = Boat.query({pagIndex: $scope.pagIndex}); // List of boats is filled correctly
};
```

and **OPTION_1:**

```
   $scope.moreResultsBoats = function() {  
        $scope.pagIndex = $scope.pagIndex + 1;                                 
        $scope.moreBoats = Boat.query({pagIndex: $scope.pagIndex});

        console.log("moreBoats:" + $scope.moreBoats);
        angular.forEach($scope.moreBoats, function(boat, key) {             
            $scope.boats.push(boat);
        });
  }
```

or **OPTION_2**:

```
$scope.moreResultsBoats = function() {  
            $scope.pagIndex = $scope.pagIndex + 1;                                 
            $scope.moreBoats = Boat.query({pagIndex: $scope.pagIndex});

            console.log("moreBoats:" + $scope.moreBoats);
            $scope.boats.push.apply($scope.boats, $scope.moreBoats);
}
```

Neither of the OPTIONS add the array of new boats in $scope.moreBoats to the $scope.boats (or at least the view is not refreshed).
I think I don´t understand something about how AngularJS works, because console.log only displays this: `moreBoats:`.

However, if I add {{moreBoats | json }} to my view, for tracking purposes, I can see the boats in json when they come.

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Roberto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for your responses @Maxim. I will try your last solution. Anyway, I have fixed it right now by updating my controller to:

```
$scope.moreResultsBoats = function() {  
            $scope.pagIndex = $scope.pagIndex + 1;                                 
            Boat.query({pagIndex: $scope.pagIndex}, 
                function success(result) {
                    console.log('Ejecuting callback. Result:' + result);
                    $scope.boats.push.apply($scope.boats, result);      
                }
            );                              
        };
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your factory `Boat` is async and returns the `promise`.

This is a reason why you get data later in `{{moreBoats | json }}`.

To make it work you can wrap the promise with `.then`.

Something like:

```
Boat.query({pagIndex: $scope.pagIndex})
                    .then(function (result) {
                       $scope.moreBoats = result;                           
                    }, function (result) {
                        alert("Error: No data returned");
                    });
```

and the factory:

```
.factory('Boat',   function($resource){          
        var boats =
         $resource('http://127.0.0.1\\:3000/:action', {}, {     
            query: {method:'GET', params:{action:'boats'}, isArray:true},
            getBoatsByBusinessId: {method:'GET', params:{action:'boatsByBusinessId'}, isArray:true}
         });


         var factory = {
            query: function (selectedSubject) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                 deferred.resolve(boats);
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
        return factory;         
      }
  )
```

*Reference about **promises**:*

> A promise represents a future value, usually a future result of an asynchronous operation, and allows us to define what will happen once this value becomes available, or when an error occurs.

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'then' at Object.BoatListCtrl.$scope.moreResultsBoats. I think this is related with AngularJS version. I´m working on AngularJS 1.0.7. Any workaround or other solution for my version?